# How to auto close a customized vue toast component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a customized toast component:

```
<template>
 <div v-show="isToastVisible" class="toast-wrapper">
 <div class="toast-conatiner">
  {{ message }}
 </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    isToastVisible: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I pass state to the property:

```
<toast :is-toast-visible="isToastVisible" message="please say the word again"/>
```

I have an action to control the value of isToastVisbible. When I want to toast some message , I set the state to true. 
What I want is to make the toast auto closed in 3 seconds, it means that I have to call a setTimeout function when I set isToastVisbible to true.

```
  commit('SET_TOAST_VISIBLILITY', true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    commit('SET_TOAST_VISIBLILITY', false);
  }, 3000);
```

I try to add watch on isToastVisbible, but it only can works at first time.

```
<template>
  <div v-show="localVisible" class="toast-wrapper">
  <div class="toast-conatiner">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    isToastVisible: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    localVisible: false,
  }),
  watch: {
    isToastVisible(v) {
      if (v) {
        this.localVisible = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.localVisible = false;
        }, 3000);
      }
    },
  },
};
```

I am trying to do a better design on the component, but I don't know what is the best practice of this. Hope somebody could give me a hand, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use toast component with `v-model` directive. In toast you may use timer to emit hide event:

```
setTimeout(() => this.$emit('input'), 3000);
```

On the parent component you may use this one:

```
<toast-component v-model="isVisible"></toast-component>
```

Or without `v-model` sugar:

```
<toast-component :value="isVisible" @input="isVisible = false"></toast-component>
```